# I want approach this when updated. Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want approach just data in this image when updated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bBq6.jpg)

Comment: Provide examples what you've tried. Formulate an exact question and do not posts screenshots but text. Read this: [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Regarding your question, you can use something like `$customer->getChanges();` to access changes on the model.

Comment: This is  first post from me in stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not super clear but I think you want

```
$customer->getChanges();
```

Here is a good article that might help:

https://medium.com/@JinoAntony/10-hidden-laravel-eloquent-features-you-may-not-know-efc8ccc58d9e

Comment: Thank you. yes i want this, i tryed it good